# Python requests.post doesnt work if I pass payload with variables

Tags: python, python-requests

step1: I'm grabbing credentials from a text file where data is in JSON format
and storing them in a variable.

```
cred_values = {'username': 'myuser', 'password': 'mypwd'}
```

Step2:

```
username = cred_values['username']

password = cred_values['password']
```

Step3: Preparing my payload, headers. And payload looks like this

```
login_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'https://xxxxxx.com.au', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

login_data = {
    'curl': 'Z2FxxxxxZ2F', (xxxx - name of my company)
    'flags': '0',
    'forcedownlevel': '0',
    'formdir': '5',
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'trusted': '4',
    'SubmitCreds': ''
}
```

Step 4: Post request

```
 login_request_url = 'https://xxxx.com.au/Logon'
 login_response = requests.post(login_request_url, headers=login_headers, data=login_data)
```

**Note**:

1. I also tried sending payload as

   ```
   login_data = {'username': '' + username + '','password': '' + password + ''}

   login_data = {'username': '' + str(username) + '','password': '' + str(password) + ''}
   ```
2. I also tried sending payload as json.dumps to the request

   ```
   login_response = requests.post(login_request_url, headers=login_headers, data=json.dumps(login_data))
   ```

I'm not getting any errors if I post the above request its not logging in.

Ex:

If I directly add my username, pwd in login_data

The Url looks like this, which means successfully logged in - 'https://xxxx.com.au/content.asp?token = xxxxx'

If I send username and pwd by grabbing from credential file

The Url looks like this which means NOT successfully logged in - 'https://xxxx.com.au/'

Comment: What goes wrong? Is your server getting the wrong message or no message at all? Or do you get an error?

Comment: This can't be your real code, because `login_headers` is undefined.  Please post your real code.

Comment: It will be a mystery if you don't add the url and other details. Because i don't know what occurred.

Comment: If you're sending json data use `json=` instead of data=

Comment: Posting using json = didnt work. it is returning 400 response

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your server is expecting you may possibly need to send the json payload as a quoted string: I think you had the following:

```
login_data = {'username': '' + username + '','password': '' + password + ''}
login_data = {'username': '' + str(username) + '','password': '' + str(password) + ''}
```

Try the following

```
login_data =  '{"username": " ' + str(username) + ' ","password": "' + str(password) + '"}'
```

Use the single quotes to go from code to string, and use the double quotes to denote a quoted value within the string (or you could do it the other way). Alternatively you could just use the same set of quotes through out and escape the ones that you want with in the string, but personally I think that get's very hard to read very quickly
e.g.

```
data =  '{\'username\': \''+ str(username) + '\',\'password\': \'' + str(password) + '\'}'
```

See if that helps